# "SSL negotiation failed" in Delphi 11

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy

I try to send eMail with the code below (taken from http://delphiprogrammingdiary.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-send-email-in-delphi.html) without success.
Constantly I receive the error ("socket error 10054 connection reset by peer" twice and finally "SSL negotiation failed") at the statement "Send(IdMessage1)" although client is successfully connected with server.

```
    procedure SendEmailClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    IdMessage1: TIdMessage;
    Attachmentfile: TIdAttachmentFile;
begin
// IO HANDLER SETTINGS //
With TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil) do
    begin
        Destination := 'mySrver.com:587';
        Host := 'mySrver.com';
        MaxLineAction := maException;
        Port := 587;
        SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
        SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
        SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
        SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
    end;
//SETTING SMTP COMPONENT DATA //
with TIdSMTP.Create(nil) do begin
    Host := 'mySrver.com';
    Port := 587;
    Username := myMailAddress; // please change to your gmail address //
    Password := myPassword;
    IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.create;
    AuthType := satDefault;
    UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
// SETTING email MESSAGE DATA //
    IdMessage1:= TIdMessage.Create(nil);
    IdMessage1.Clear;
// add recipient list //
    with IdMessage1.Recipients.Add do
        begin
            Name := 'Recipient 1';
            Address := recipient1Address; // please change email address as required //
        end;
//add Attachment to mail //
    Attachmentfile := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdMessage1.MessageParts,'Τιμολόγιο 659.PDF');
    IdMessage1:= TIdMessage.Create(nil);
    IdMessage1.From.Address :=  myMailAddress;  // please change to your gmail address //;
    IdMessage1.Subject := 'Test Email Subject';
    IdMessage1.Body.Add('Test Email Body');
    IdMessage1.Priority := mpHigh;
    TRY
        Connect(); // no problem here. it connects always 
        Send(IdMessage1); // raises the error SSL negotiation failed
        ShowMessage('Email sent');
        Disconnect();
    except on e:Exception do
        begin
            ShowMessage(e.Message);
            Disconnect();
        end;
    END;
    IdMessage1.Free;
    IOHandler.Free;
end;
AttachmentFile.Free;
end;
```

Can you help me please ?

PS1. The same problem raises with any MAPI server (myServer, GMail, Yahoo etc)
PS2. The SSL DLLs are present and they are used by the same application to connect for other purpose without this problem.

Comment: you create TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.create twice and lose the first settings of TLS version; stop using WITH

Comment: @complete_stranger. YES! you are absolutely right. I create IOhandler and IdMessage1 twice !  Now I can sent the mail. THANKS

Answer (score 5):

You are creating a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` object and configuring it, but then you discard and leak it and then create and use another `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` object with default settings. Get rid of the second object, use the first object instead.

You are also creating 2 `TIdMessage` objects, as well. Get rid of the second one.

Also, you don't need to set the `Host`, `Port`, and `Destination` properties on the `SSLIOHandler`. `Connect()` will handle that for you.

Try this:

```
procedure SendEmailClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  IdSMTP: TIdSMTP;
  IdMessage1: TIdMessage;
  Attachmentfile: TIdAttachmentFile;
  IdSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  //SETTING SMTP COMPONENT DATA //
  IdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IdSMTP.Host := 'mySrver.com';
    IdSMTP.Port := 587;
    IdSMTP.Username := myMailAddress; // please change to your gmail address
    // Password := myPassword;
    IdSMTP.AuthType := satDefault;
    IdSMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;

    // IO HANDLER Settings //
    IdSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdSMTP);
    IdSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
    IdSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
    IdSSL.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    IdSSL.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
    IdSMTP.IOHandler := IdSSL;

    // SETTING email MESSAGE DATA //
    IdMessage1 := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
    try
      // add recipient list //
      with IdMessage1.Recipients.Add do
      begin
        Name := 'Recipient 1';
        Address := recipient1Address; // please change email address as required //
      end;
      //add Attachment to mail //
      Attachmentfile := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdMessage1.MessageParts, 'Τιμολόγιο 659.PDF');
      IdMessage1.From.Address := myMailAddress; // please change to your gmail address //;
      IdMessage1.Subject := 'Test Email Subject';
      IdMessage1.Body.Add('Test Email Body');
      IdMessage1.Priority := mpHigh;

      try
        IdSMTP.Connect();
        try
          IdSMTP.Send(IdMessage1);
          ShowMessage('Email sent');
        finally
          IdSMTP.Disconnect();
        end;
      except
        on e: Exception do
        begin
          ShowMessage(e.Message);
        end;
      end;
    finally
      IdMessage1.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdSMTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Remy. Now I am able to sent mails from my app